# ICC and Clusters

Tags: intraclass-correlation, clustered-standard-errors

I'm studying a dataset of 10,400 observations (schools) across Italy. My dependent variable is at school level, while among my explanatory variables I have some of them at province level (the main regressor is social capital). Thus, I was thinking to use clustered SE at province level (with different number of observations). My ICC output is:

[image]

An ICC of .19 is high? Is it correct in this case to use a cluster(prov) SE?